# Boost Python (Suse and Ubuntu)

Tags: c++, python, boost, ubuntu, suse

I created a simple .so library containing definition of a C++ class which should be accessed from Python and used for this purpose boost python library.
When I'm testing this library using x64 Ubuntu it is enough to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the path to boost libs before running python. It doesn't work, however, when I'm using x64 Suse.
Altough I'm setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH it seems that Python ignores it.

Is there any specific way to set environmental variables under Suse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, see [here](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) and [here](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html).
First of all I have to assume that you installed the Boost libraries in a nonstandard location, otherwise the loader would find them automatically. If you have root access to the machine, install the libraries in a standard place (e.g. with the package manager, or in `/usr/local/lib`).

If you don't have root privileges, set the runpath instead. When using the gcc linker, do this by passing an `-rpath` option. The gcc compiler can pass options to the linker via `-Wl`. So call the compiler as follows:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wl,-rpath /path/to/boost -L /path/to/boost -lboost_python ...
```